# Reinstall Summary Fields Not Creating Triggers

Tags: database, summaryfields

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Summary Fields a couple of times trying to get the triggers to show up on the admin screen as having been recreated.  I started looking into this because we have a transient problem when saving contributions. I think that when the database was restored I did no recreate them and now they are not recreated by reinstalling Summary Fields.

[image]

I just want to rebuild the triggers.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Did you try https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#trigger-rebuild ?

Comment: @Demerit, I have done everything for Drupal other than got back to a previous version of CiviCRM. I am not sure when this goes back to have know what version to go back to and we would loose to much data to go back 6 months or so.

Comment: The link suggests just going to http://example.org/civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1&triggerRebuild=1, but replace example.org with your site. It should rebuild triggers.

Comment: Unless that is working and not updating the screen (the checks over the circles) then that URL is not working.